# Is there a way to SET the address of a variable?

Tags: c#, memory

I'd like to know if it's possible to set a variable's address so that it is always the same at runtime.

Say that I wanted to be able to look at address 0xA100, and that address **always** has the value of Var. Maybe I could create a pointer to Var at address 0xA100?

[This Rosetta Code entry](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Address_of_a_variable) shows how to set addresses in C/C++, but not C#. Does this mean there is no way at all to do this in C#?

EDIT: I'm wanting to create an Autosplitter for a game. Basically it just listens for a certain address and then starts/stops an external timer depending on the value at that address. I know that I can just find pointers using Cheat Engine, but I've never had good luck with pointer scans. If I could just modify the game so that I know the exact address, that would be ideal.

Comment: You can start from reading about [`unsafe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unsafe) keyword, I assume.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Yeah you can pin memory in various ways, But I am curious as to why this is important to you, and whether or not this is an XY problem

Comment: Also, you should realize that this is still going to be a translated address to your process' virtual memory space. This isn't the good ol' [real mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_mode) DOS days.

Comment: @TheGeneral it's essentially so I could create a plugin for a game that stops/start a timer depending on the state of certain variables

Comment: Like I mentioned, your process' 0xA100 memory address is not the same as another process' 0xA100 memory address in the virtual memory world we live in. You first need to access the other process' memory and map to it. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50672268/c-sharp-reading-another-process-memory.

Comment: @itsme86 I'm not writing an external program, I'm wanting to modify the game itself to change the variable's address. After that there's a totally separate thing that attaches itself to the game process and reads the game's "0xA100" address

Comment: @NotJerrett You cant easily change the address another application expects a variable/whatever. Its kind of like asking if its possible to change where the tire goes on somebodies car while they are driving, you can see how many problems you would run in to, its the same with what you are proposing. Sure anything can be done if you have the will, yet it would be very difficult to get stable and right. You can however, locate memory in another application, poll it for changes and change the value ect.

Comment: I don't fully understand your requirements, but if you already know how to achieve it in C/C++ perhaps a good option would be building a C++/CLI library.  Your library will be very easy to call from C# (no funky p-invoke stuff) and you can drop the relevant C++ code and it will work.