# How to access a external memory in c# program

Tags: c#

I have an exercise in college where I need to access the value of an external program, and for that I need to use its memory address. Unfortunately, I have a System.AccessViolation problem. Is there another way to access the value of an address external to my program? (first code is that of the program that gives me the address, the second is the one that should read the address and show its value)

```
 static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x = 100;
        int* ptr = &x;
        Console.WriteLine((int)ptr);
        Console.WriteLine(*ptr);
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine((int)ptr);
    }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IntPtr bufPtr = new IntPtr(-1705515732);
    byte[] data = new byte[32];
    Marshal.Copy(bufPtr, data, 0, 32);
    Console.WriteLine((int)bufPtr);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: You cannot simply access a random memory address in a modern operating system, those are all guarded in various ways. You'd need to first request access to the process (with something like `OpenProcess` from the Win32 API) and then request that process' memory

Comment: I strongly hope that won't be possible, otherwise a ton of problems would put a risk safety and security of many systems!

Comment: See e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50672268/c-sharp-reading-another-process-memory

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: i am using a win 10